# Como alterar o estilo de um componente sem criar outro componente com Styled Components

Tags: react, styled-components

Possuo no arquivo LoginWrapper.js a importação de um Grid do material design:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
```

Possuo no arquivo LoginStyles.js a alteração de css desse componente:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const GridMaterial = styled(Grid)`
    height: 100vh;
    backgroundColor: red;
`

export default GridMaterial;
```

Como posso aplicar o estilo GridMaterial no meu grid?
Eu importei no meu arquivo LoginWrapper.js os estilos da page Login:

```
import LoginStyles from './login-form/LoginStyles'
```

E tentei utilizar no meu componente a classe:

```
 <Grid className={LoginStyles.GridMaterial} container component="main">
```

Porém a classe não foi aplicada no elemento.
Como eu posso aplicar essa classe no meu grid?

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, quando você cria uma styled-component, você cria um novo COMPONENTE e não uma nova classecss ou um novo objeto de estilo.

Logo, você precisa utilizar esse componente diretamente.

Ao invés de:

```
<Grid className={LoginStyles.GridMaterial} container component="main">
```

Será:

```
import GridMaterial from './login-form/LoginStyles';

<GridMaterial container component="main">...
```